# Get HTML content with styles in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an application created using Angular. I need to get `html` of template of some big component but with styles that used there for classes. How can I do that in angular? Currently I'm trying to achieve this with getting `innerHTML`:

```
const myTemplate = document.getElementById("someWrapperId");
const content = myContent.innerHTML;
```

It doesn't return styled html.
I also tried with setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` - it also doesn't help in my case.
Styles are set in component.css file and not inline.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can use `@ViewChild` and `ElementRef` to get the HTML content style. I have a sample code below =>
**HTML:**

```
<div  #infoDiv class='col-md-2' style='color: blue;width:152px'>INFO DIV</div>
<br>
Your Color:: {{styleColor}}
<br>
Your Width:: {{styleWidth}}
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  styleColor:any='';
  styleWidth:any='';
  @ViewChild('infoDiv') infoDivRef: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.infoDivRef.nativeElement) {
      console.log(this.infoDivRef.nativeElement.style.color);
      this.styleColor=this.infoDivRef.nativeElement.style.color;
       this.styleWidth=this.infoDivRef.nativeElement.style.width;
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Code is also available in stackblitz. Please check the LINK [DEMO link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-html-content-with-styles-in-angular-hvv2gn?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: This won't work with styles in separate file. That's the case I want it to work in.